# PHP AJAX contact form dosen't send email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, contacts

Trying to get an AJAX contact form to send the email but it dosen't work and, after throrough research, I still can't get what's wrong, so maybe one of you can help.

**JS:**

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['message'])){
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];  
$message = $_POST['message']; 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'email@email.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

$response = array(); } 

echo json_encode($response); 

die; 
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="contact-form bottom">
    <h2>Send a message</h2>
    <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email Id">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea>
        </div>                        
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Please help! I'm out of options.

Comment: Please check i.e. port 25 is open to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

The data parameter is missing from you ajax function.

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');

form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: { // pass the data values sending through ajax
              name : name,
              email : email,
              message : message
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

You can obtain the values you want to send over through ajax to your php script as following:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var message = $('#message').val();
```

Once you have obtained these values you can call the ajax function passing those as data parameters and setting the data type as `POST`. Then in your PHP script you can get the post values exactly as you did.

Comment: I have already provided the corrected code. You need only to pass as parameter the values you want to send over to your php script.

Comment: I've added `"name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,` and it doesn't work

Comment: This is a string, you have to add as an object(array). If you want to add as a string you have to convert the string to an array in php.

Comment: Please show me how, based on thec code. My head is blowing up.

Comment: I know I sound stupid, and I am when it comes to JS and PHP since I'm new to all this. So what I'm asking is... can you please give me an exact example of the object(array) I have to add there? I can't find anything that works

Comment: Well, I highly appreciate your answers, but if you don't basically "spoonfeed" me the code for both PHP and JS, I won't be able to do it. Of course, I've added the new JS (which dosen't even confirm the mail has been sent, like it used to before, even though it was not actually sending it), but I don't have any idea where to place the PHP code you gave me. Like I've said, I'm stupid when it comes to back-end, and it's even more annoying that this is just a simple contact form I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

where is $subject initialised? I don't see it getting value in php code before sending it to the mail function

Comment: Do one thing add some value to $subject before calling mail function, then use success to check if ajax call is made properly

Answer (score 0):

To send email you need to configure something like this, also you need to use
Less Secure Apps to be enabled (in case of Gmail). To enable Less Secure you
need to login to your account then click following link:

http://know.mailsbestfriend.com/smtp_error_password_command_failed_5345714-1194946499.shtml

```
public function sendEmail($email, $subject, $message) {                                                                                                
    $config= array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'example@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap'  => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('localhost', 'Team Name');
    $this->email->to($email); 
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);    
    if(!$this->email->send()){
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
}
```

Comment: The PHP code does its job and it is sending the email it I delete the JS code, so there's no problem there.